# Change the default allure-report path for allure jenkins configuration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, allure

In the jenkins configuration the default value for Report path is allure-report.
Is there a way to change this default value?
[image: Allure default path]

I want to change it to take the JOB_NAME parameter.
I tried the following options and it doesn't work. While generating the allure report the command does not take the JOB_NAME parameter.

- ${JOB_NAME}/allure-report
- "$JOB_NAME"/allure-report
- $JOB_NAME/allure-report

[image: allure report generation command]

My reason for changing the default value: I use a custom_workspace for some of the jenkins jobs, to do space management on the test server. I would like to keep the allure-report and allure-results separate for each job.

Comment: There is no option (see [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/allure-plugin/blob/0b5b895ec841be8a91560e0e88b590d87f2c974c/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/allure/jenkins/AllureReportBuildAction.java)) the 'allure-report' is hardcoded as the default value.

Comment: :(

thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @NoamHelmer is it possible to create a folder with a timestamp so a report for each session ends up in a folder?

Comment: I think so, within the report folder you can arrange the results however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Groovy script, then you can provide your custom directories for the allure to serve the results as shown below:

```
post {
script {
                allure([
                        includeProperties: false,
                        jdk: '',
                        properties: [],
                        reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                        results: [[path: '${WORKSPACE}/test-reports/report-1']]
                ])
            }
    }
```